# EditActionsforRow: Close Programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am working on implementing some custom actions into my tableview.  Currently I have created a custom action in below code.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {

//my custom report Action
            var reportAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Normal, title: "report problem with product") { (myaction, indexPath) -> Void in
                println(myaction)

                println(indexPath)

//Close the action programmaticaly


            }
            reportAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()


            return [reportAction]
```

After I implement the action, and swipe to the left. It correctly displays the purple label with "report problem with product"

The problem is that there seems to be no way to make the table cell swipe back to the regular table view programmaticallys. It thus gets stuck on the screen below.

[image]
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to run.

```
tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
```

Comment: any way to programmatically open?